# pandas memory error while converting column of large csv from string to float

Tags: python, pandas, memory

I have a large csv (~20 mil rows) and I'd like to convert one column from string to float. I do this way:

```
df['sale']=df['sale'].str.replace(",", ".").astype('float32')
```

and sale looks like:

```
86,2600
20,2800 
123,5000
30,7500
8,3600
```

The command seems unstable, i.e sometimes gives the following memory error:

> MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 df['sale']=df['sale'].str.replace(",", ".").astype('float32');

What is exactly this error and how can I fix it? 
Thank you!

Comment: how big is the column

Comment: Just tell pandas to treat this as a decimal separator `pd.read_csv(FILENAME, decimal=',')` when reading so it converts on reading

Comment: @EdChum this seems to be the trick! thanks

Comment: If it works let me know and I'll post as an answer

Comment: maybe numpy is more efficient with memory? 

import numpy as np
df['sale']=np.core.defchararray.replace(df['sale'].values, ',', '.').astype('float32')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than converting after loading which is a memory intensive operation. You can specify that the decimal separator is European style by passing the param `decimal=','` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv):

```
pd.read_csv(FILENAME, decimal=',')
```

Example:

```
In[24]:
t="""data
86,2600
20,2800 
123,5000
30,7500
8,3600"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), decimal=',', sep=';')
df

Out[24]: 
     data
0   86.26
1   20.28
2  123.50
3   30.75
4    8.36
```

Note that I pass `sep=';'` otherwise it will treat the above as 2 columns as the default separator is comma.

We can see that the output shows that it's decimal, and we can confirm the `dtype` using `.info()`:

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 1 columns):
data    5 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 120.0 bytes
```